# Google chrome spellcheck will find errors but not fix them

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Recently Chrome developed an issue. It will redline spelling errors like usual. But when I rightclick on the word, and select the correct spelling, it randomly fails to replace the misspelled text. Once it has failed on a given word, it will always fail on the word. But there is no way yo know which words will fail.

This has failed to correct the word three times while I was typing this, but worked fine twice.

Answer (score 1):

I turned off the option to "ask Google for suggestions" and it started working again!

I had exactly the same problem, and I think it cropped up the same time for me as it did you.

For me, the failure to correct words wasn't random, it only affected specific words. For instance, it would never correct becuase to because, although it would fix my less frequent errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple variants of English (`English`, `English (US)` and `English (UK)`) in my language configuration. Removing the duplicates fixed the issue for me.